# How do you say "I am in the 9th grade"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do you say "I am in the 9th Grade"?

> Ich bin **in der 9ten** Klasse.

Comment: You are almost right but in writing it's "Ich bin in der 9. Klasse".

Comment: Or, of course: Ich bin in der neunten Klasse.

Comment: @Vineeth, feel free to post your answer as an answer ;)

Comment: "Ich gehe in die 9. Klasse" is way more common and idiomatic where I come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your guess right in your question. Circumstantially,

- In writing it's "Ich bin in der 9. Klasse".
- Spelled out "Ich bin in der neunten Klasse".
- Pronounced [ɪç bɪn ɪn deɐ̯ nɔɪ̯ntn ˈklasə].

Comment: English being a language with very irregular pronunciation, I don't see any advantage in writing a German sentence in "English phonetics". I moreover suspect that it motivates a wrong pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

> Ich bin in der 9. Klasse. / Ich bin in der neunten Klasse. (colloquial-normal register)
>
> Ich gehe in die 9. Klasse. / Ich gehe in die neunte Klasse. (colloquial-normal register)
>
> Ich besuche die 9. Klasse. / Ich besuche die neunte Klasse. (normal-elevated register)
>
> Ich bin 9.-Klässler. / Ich bin Neuntklässler. (colloquial-normal register, seldomly used in first person)

And instead of `Klasse` one can also say `Klassenstufe`.